# I'm still not sure why the reverse state is not working?

Tags: unity, c#

The goal is to be able to change direction(reverse or forward) at runtime in real time without waiting the transform to reach the next waypoint first but at real time to change the direction/s.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> waypoints = new List<GameObject>();
    public float movementSpeed;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public bool reverse = false;
    public bool go = false;
    public int nextWaypointNumber;
    public int lastWaypointNumber;
    public bool stopState = false;
    public bool stopAtFirstWP = false;
    public bool loop = false;

    private int waypointIndex = 0;
    private GameObject nextWayPoint;
    private GameObject lastWayPoint;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint").ToList();

        if (reverse)
        {
            waypointIndex = waypoints.Count - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            waypointIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go)
        {
            ReverseState();

            if (stopState)
            {
                StopState(stopAtFirstWP);
            }

            nextWayPoint = waypoints[waypointIndex];
            nextWaypointNumber = waypointIndex;

            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
            waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * movementSpeed);

            float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position);
            if (distance > 1f)
            {
                var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(nextWayPoint.transform.position - transform.position);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
            }
            else
            {
                if (reverse)
                {
                    waypointIndex--;
                }
                else
                {
                    waypointIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void StartMovingAfterSeconds(float seconds)
    {
        StartCoroutine(MoveNpc(seconds));
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveNpc(float seconds)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);

        go = true;
    }

    private void StopState(bool stopAtFirstWP)
    {
        if (stopAtFirstWP && waypointIndex == 1)
        {
            go = false;
        }

        if (stopAtFirstWP == false && waypointIndex == waypoints.Count - 1)
        {
            go = false;
        }
    }

    private void ReverseState()
    {
        if (reverse && waypointIndex == 0)
        {
            waypointIndex = waypoints.Count - 1;
        }

        if (reverse == false && waypointIndex == waypoints.Count)
        {
            waypointIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        if (waypoints != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Count; i++)
            {
                Gizmos.color = Color.green;
                Gizmos.DrawSphere(waypoints[i].transform.position, 0.1f);
            }
        }

        if (nextWayPoint != null)
        {
            Gizmos.color = Color.red;
            Gizmos.DrawLine(transform.position, nextWayPoint.transform.position);
        }
    }
}
```

I have a reverse flag and this ReverseState method :

```
private void ReverseState()
    {
        if (reverse && waypointIndex == 0)
        {
            waypointIndex = waypoints.Count - 1;
        }

        if (reverse == false && waypointIndex == waypoints.Count)
        {
            waypointIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

but when running the game and changing the reverse flag true or false many times it's not changing the direction/s and after once or two throw exception out of range at the line :

```
nextWayPoint = waypoints[waypointIndex];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have over-engineered this problem a little, possibly due to not knowing you can simply reverse lists of things.

Here's how I'd do it.

```
using NaughtyAttributes;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Patroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> WayPoints;

    private int CurrentWayPoint = 0;
    private bool IsPatrolling = false;
    private bool PingPong = false;

    private int CachedPingPongIndex;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartPatrol();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            ReversePatrolWayPoints();
        }


        ///We need to store the CurrentWayPoint when the ping pong button is pressed (outside of the patrol loop)
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            PingPong = !PingPong;
            CachedPingPongIndex = CurrentWayPoint;
        }
    }

    //Simple Method so you can start the patrol from anywhere while checking its not already running
    public void StartPatrol()
    {
        if (!IsPatrolling)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Patrol());
        }      
    }


    //Reverse the list!
    public void ReversePatrolWayPoints()
    {
        WayPoints.Reverse();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start a Patrol through the way points
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerator Patrol()
    {
        if (WayPoints == null || WayPoints.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waypoints list is null or empty");
            yield break;
        }

        IsPatrolling = true;

        while (CurrentWayPoint < WayPoints.Count)
        {
            int cachedWayPoint = CurrentWayPoint;
            float distanceToWayPoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, 0.1f);

            if (distanceToWayPoint <= 1f)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("Reached Waypoint {0}", CurrentWayPoint);
                CurrentWayPoint++;


                //Check if ping pong is enabled if so, we use the value we cached when the button was pressed + 1
                //so if we press ping pong on Point 8, then we cehck if the current way point we are on is greater than cached value + 1 so 9 in this example, if the currentwaypoint is greater than this number then we reset back to the cached value and loop these two points
                if (PingPong)
                {
                    if (CurrentWayPoint > CachedPingPongIndex + 1)
                    {
                        CurrentWayPoint = CachedPingPongIndex;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (CurrentWayPoint >= WayPoints.Count)
                    {
                        CurrentWayPoint = 0;
                    }
                }


 
            }

            yield return null;
        }


        IsPatrolling = false;
        yield break;
    }
}
```

As you may notice, it doesn't matter to the patroller which order the list is in, it simply knows it must move to the position of the GameObject in the WayPoints list at the *current index*, if you reverse the list and therefore which point the index refers to, the patroller will start moving there.

The "Ping Pong" loop is not too different, instead what we are manipulating  is *when* we decide to reset the patrol point, the main thing to take away is we needed to store the CurrentWayPoint as a seperate variable when the button is pressed, then if Ping Pong mode is enabled we check what way point  we are on against the cached value + 1.

So if the button is pressed on WayPoint 8,

`CachedPingPongIndex = 8`

`CachedPingPongIndex + 1 = 9`

`if(CurrentWayPoint > 9) > Reset To 8`

Given this information we can check while patroling if we try to increase the currentway point index above our cached value + 1 we can reset the CurrentWayPoint index to what we initially cached the value at, letting us loop between these two points.

Comment: Working great.  How can I add pingpong ? If I press on the P key it will keep moving to the next waypoint and then will return to the last visited waypoint and make a nonstop pingpong between the two points.  no matter where the transform is if for example at waypoint 7 then reach to 8 and then make pingpong between 8 and 7.

Comment: because I want to use later with Vector3.MoveTowards so I don't want to use Mathf.PingPong and Lerp.  but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Updated the answer with some commenting, should do what you want.

Comment: I tested it noe and it's working but if I press the p key few times in a row to change the pinpong between the waypoints after few times it stop at the next waypoint and never continue.  I press the p pingpong it's making pingpong then if I press again the transform will keep moving between all waypoints then I press the p key again and then at specific time when I press the p key again the transform will stop at the last waypoint or next waypoint and stay there will not move again.

Comment: seems like "pause"  not pausing the game but the waypoints movement the transform just stay and hang at the next waypoint I think if I press p key fast when the transform is at the next way point or in this case also the last waypoint in the waypoints list.  the transform just hang there never move again.